# What can be done when installing an RPM package results in a digest mismatch error?

Tags: package-management, rpm

```
fatal: [server_hostname]: FAILED! => { "changed": true, "cmd": [ "rpm", "--install", "--force", "--replacefiles", "--nodigest", "--nosignature", "/path/to/directorycheck-mk-agent-2.2.0p12-a7d0a8ccb7c75fc3.noarch.rpm" ], "delta": "0:00:00.097047", "end": "2023-11-07 14:18:21.430416", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-11-07 14:18:21.333369", "stderr": "error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/check_mk/super-server.cfg;654a8d7d: cpio: Digest mismatchnerror: check-mk-agent-2.2.0p12-1.a7d0a8ccb7c75fc3.noarch: install failed", "stderr_lines": [ "error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/check_mk/super-server.cfg;654a8d7d: cpio: Digest mismatch", "error: check-mk-agent-2.2.0p12-1.a7d0a8ccb7c75fc3.noarch: install failed" ], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [] }
```

I have already attempted to re-download the package to rule out corruption and verified the checksum. The error persists only on these two servers, and there are no apparent issues with the RPM database that I can detect. The --nodigest option does not seem to bypass the issue as expected.

I am reaching out to ask for advice or insights into the following:

1. What could be causing a digest mismatch error on specific servers even when using the --nodigest option?
2. Are there known issues with RPM or specific system configurations that could lead to this kind of problem?
3. Is there a more recommended approach to forcefully install an RPM package when encountering a digest mismatch?

Note: Here is the reason chatgtp gave me for the error: The error message you're seeing indicates that the RPM installation failed due to a "Digest mismatch" on the file /etc/check_mk/super-server.cfg. This means that the checksum of the file within the RPM package does not match the expected checksum calculated by the rpm command. Here are some possible reasons for this issue:

- Corrupted RPM Package: The RPM file might have been corrupted during download, transfer, or storage. This could cause the checksum to not match what the rpm command expects.
- Altered Configuration File: If the configuration file /etc/check_mk/super-server.cfg has been manually altered or tampered with after the RPM was created, its digest will no longer match the one stored in the RPM database.(It has not been altered)
- Existing File With Different Contents: There might be an existing /etc/check_mk/super-server.cfg file from a previous installation or another source with different contents, causing a conflict when the RPM tries to install its version. (How do I check for previous version?)
- Incorrect RPM Version: If you're trying to install an RPM that is not intended for your specific system or version, it might contain files that are not compatible, leading to a digest mismatch.